# time discretization in for-loop in R

Tags: r, function, for-loop

I have a function to be calculated in three different innings by calculating it backwards in time due to time discretization. The time step is denoted by h. And h can be h=1/12, h=1/100, and h=1000 . The three values for the function ​​should be similar since we calculate them in the same range just with different time discretization . If we assume h=1/12 and I will then compute a function of all sequences in the range 65:60.

```
h<-1/12
a <- seq(65, 60, (-h)) 

[1] 65.00000 64.91667 64.83333 64.75000 64.66667 64.58333 64.50000 64.41667 64.33333 64.25000 64.16667
[12] 64.08333 64.00000 63.91667 63.83333 63.75000 63.66667 63.58333 63.50000 63.41667 63.33333 63.25000
[23] 63.16667 63.08333 63.00000 62.91667 62.83333 62.75000 62.66667 62.58333 62.50000 62.41667 62.33333
[34] 62.25000 62.16667 62.08333 62.00000 61.91667 61.83333 61.75000 61.66667 61.58333 61.50000 61.41667
[45] 61.33333 61.25000 61.16667 61.08333 61.00000 60.91667 60.83333 60.75000 60.66667 60.58333 60.50000
[56] 60.41667 60.33333 60.25000 60.16667 60.08333 60.00000
```

These values ​​are given:

```
mu10<-function(t){return(alfa+beta*exp(gamma*t))} 
#mu20=1.03*mu10 #(i write this one in the for-loop)
mu12<-0.5
mu21<-3
r<-log(1+0.01)
b1<-(-1500)
b2<-25000*0.15*12
c10<-45000*10
c20<-45000*10
gamma<-0.044
alpha<-(-0.0073)
beta<-0.0009
```

What I want to do: Create a for loop that calculates this:

**v(65)**=h*(b1+mu10*c10+mu12)

**w(65)**=h*(b2+mu20*c20+mu21)

*v(64.91667)*=**v(65)**+h*(-r * v(65)+b1+mu10 * (c10-v(65))+mu12*(w(65)-v(65)))

*w(64.91667)*=**w(65)**+h*(-r * w(65)+b2+mu20 * (c20-w(65))+mu21*(v(65)-w(65)))

v(64.83333)=*v(64.91667)*+h*(-r* v(64.91667)+b1+mu10*(c10-v(64.91667))+mu12*(w(64.91667)-v(64.91667)))

w(64.83333)=*w(64.91667)*+h*(-r* w(64.91667)+b1+mu10*(c10-w(64.91667))+mu12*(v(64.91667)-w(64.91667)))

. . . . .

v(60)=....

w(60)=....

So as you can see, the equations depend on each other. The equation in the previous step depends on the one we calculate.

I am interested to find out v(60) and w(60) is when we use time discretization.

What I 've tested:

```
h<-1/12
a <- seq(65, 60, (-h)) 
v <- a*0
w <- a*0
mu10<-function(t){return(alfa+beta*exp(gamma*t))} 
#mu20=1.03*mu10 #(i write this one in the for-loop)
mu12<-0.5
mu21<-3
r<-log(1+0.01)
b1<-(-1500)
b2<-25000*0.15*12
c10<-45000*10
c20<-45000*10
gamma<-0.044
alpha<-(-0.0073)
beta<-0.0009

for (t in 2:length(a)){
  v[1] <- h*(b1+mu10(a[t])*c10)
  w[1] <- h*(b2+mu10(a[t])*1.03*c20)
  v[t] <- v[t-1]+h*(-r*v[t-1]+b1+mu10(a[t])*(c10-v[t-1])+mu12*(w[t-1]-v[t-1]))
  w[t] <- w[t-1]+h*(-r*w[t-1]+b2+mu10(a[t])*1.03*(c20-w[t-1])+mu21*(v[t-1]-w[t-1]))
}
v[60]
w[60]
```

**The problem is: When I change the h to h=1/100 och h=1000 (different length of time discretization), I get completely different value of v[60] and w[60] when i change h.
I think they should be similar .Because we stop and want to know the function value when t = 60 when h is 1/12, 1/100 or 1/1000
There is something wrong in the code because it is the "same" function and h is only the actual time discretization how we chop up the interval we calculate . Tips on code ?**

when h=1/12

```
> v[60]
[1] 37606.36
> w[60]
[1] 50852.52
```

when h=1/100

```
> v[60]
[1] 3612.329
> w[60]
[1] 15315.34
```

when h=1000

```
> v[60]
[1] 175.1585
> w[60]
[1] 2700.449
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You read out the 60th iteration step. If you subset a vector with a number `x` you receive the `x`th element of this vector. You are interested in the last iteration step where the time = 60. You can either subset with `a==60` or, since you are only interested in the last element, simply with `length(a)`.

This results in:

h=1/12

```
v[length(a)]
38184.65
w[length(a)]
51430.8
```

h = 1/100

```
v[length(a)]
37607.17
w[length(a)]
50853.34
```

h = 1/1000

```
v[length(a)]
37536.09
w[length(a)]
50782.26
```